# How i do use Search filter in Zealdocs with .NET document?

Tags: .net, zeal

How i do use Search filter in **Zealdocs** with **.NET** document ?
From official website say (https://zealdocs.org/usage.html) :
**python:string** will search only docsets related to Python for string
I did try with .NET in many way, It doesn't work.

All below solution doesn't work for me.

```
.net:String
.NET:String
NET Framework:String
"NET Framework":String
NET_Framework:String
NET.Framework:String
NET-Framework:String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net:String`

Unfortunately, for .NET docset it's not quite obvious. I am working on improving the situation.

P.S. For better response times please one of the [contact methods](https://zealdocs.org/contact.html) listed on our website, e.g. IRC channel (#zealdocs @ FreeNode).